# Permission Denied Error Compiling CSS/JS with Laravel Mix in Docker Image

Tags: linux, docker, npm, permissions, compilation

I'm encountering a permission error while compiling CSS/JS files using Laravel Mix within a Docker image.
I encountered the following error:
`｢wdm｣: Error: EACCES: permission denied`

To provide context, here are the steps I've followed.

1.Built the Docker image using `docker-compose build` and started the container

2.Connected to the container as root `docker-compose exec wordpress bash`

3.Installed npm & rebuild node-sass `npm rebuild node-sass`

4.Exited the container and connected as www-data `docker-compose exec -u www-data wordpress bash`

5.Attempted to run `npm run build` which contains the following `cross-env NODE_ENV=development      node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`

After that I get the above permission error. My Docker version is 20.10.21.  Additionally, my Laravel Mix version is 5.0.7, and I'm using npm version 6.14.4.

How can I resolve this permission issue and successfully compile my assets using Laravel Mix within my Docker image? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!